# wxpython start multiple timers within a for loop

Tags: python, loops, timer, wxpython

I want to create and start multiple timers in a for loop. My approach has been as follows:

```
import wx

trials = range(1, 3)
timers = range(7)
name = 'timer'

class TimersClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.button1 = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Go')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Timers, self.button1)

    def Timers(self, event):
        for trial in trials:
            for timer in timers:
                setattr(self, name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial), wx.Timer(self))
                print name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial)

                eval(name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial) + '.Start(' + str(timer * 1000, ) + ', OneShoot = True)')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Hi)

    def Hi(self, event):
        print 'Hi, bastard!'


app = wx.App()
frame = TimersClass(None)
frame.Center()
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

But the self.timers objects appear not to be created:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Escritorio/iteration_timers.py", line 24, in Timers
    eval(name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial) + '.Start(' + str(timer * 1000, ) + ', OneShoot = True)')
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'timer0_iteration1' is not defined

Someone knows why this code doesn't run, or have an alternative approach?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't know much about scoping in `eval`, but I don't see the object `timer0_iteration1` to be defined anywhere. Where should it come from?

Comment: I create it with the setattr method. Now I use an alternative approach, creating the string  "self.timer0_iteration1" and then creating the timer via exec("self.timer0_iteration1 = wx.Timer(self)").

Comment: Myself again. I made a mistake: the method is called "oneShot" instead of "OneShoot". My timers are now created and running using the exec instead of eval function. eval gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Escritorio/iteration_timers.py", line 20, in Timers
    eval('self.' + name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial) + ' = wx.Timer(self)')
  File "<string>", line 1
    self.timer0_iteration1 = wx.Timer(self)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But with exec it run correctly.

Best wishes,
Mauricio.

Comment: In adition, now I realize that instead of this ugly syntax

eval(name + str(timer) + '_' + 'iteration' + str(trial) + '.Start(' + str(timer * 1000, ) + ', OneShoot = True)')

I must had write somethign like

timer_method = 'self.timer%s%s.Start(%s, %s)' %(str(timer), str(trial), str(timer * 1000), str(one_shot))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a reasonable structure within the class to store the timers (rather than creating a bunch of class attributes with complicated encoded names).  Here's an example:

```
import wx

trial_range = range(1, 3)
timer_range = range(7)

class TimersClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Go')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BuildTimers, self.button1)

        self.timers = {}  # a structure to hold the timers

    def BuildTimers(self, event):
        for trial in trial_range:
            for timer in timer_range:
                new_timer = wx.Timer(self)
                new_timer.Start(1 + timer*1000, oneShot=True)

                key = (trial, timer)
                self.timers[key] = new_timer # to keep the timer in the class
                new_timer.mykey = key  #optional: to know the key of the timer via the event (see Hi())

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Hi)

    def Hi(self, event):
        print "timer:",
        print event.GetEventObject().mykey


app = wx.PySimpleApp() 
frame = TimersClass(None)
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When this runs it produces:

```
timer: (1, 0)
timer: (2, 0)
timer: (1, 1)
timer: (2, 1)
timer: (1, 2)
# etc
```

Comment: Wow!
It works fine and fix another problem I have: how to bind the different timers to different events in Hi(). Now with sometihn like `if event.GetEventObject() == self.timers[(trial, timer)]:` it should run.  Thanks a lot!  (I tried to give you +1 in your reputation, but I'm new and I can't unless I have 15)

Comment: Hey!
There is a better way with `if event.GetEventObject() == self.timers[event.GetEventObject().mykey]:`. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear this worked for you.  There are a bunch of ways to respond to different events.  What you do works.  I thought you'd just do something like, `if event.GetEventObject().mykey==(1,2)`  Or, when you build `self.timers` you can make a dictionary with the same keys, but with the responses you like to take.  Or you can use `functools.partial` or `lambda` as described in FogleBird's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976395/best-way-to-get-the-name-of-a-button-that-called-an-event