# wxPython: binding a dynamically created spinner to an event

Tags: events, wxpython

I used the code below to create several spinners with a for loop.

Now, I can't figure out how to bind an event so  that I know which spinner is being modified so that I can put the spinner value into the right variable.

If I can figure out which spinner is calling the handler I could map it to the correct variable.

Any thoughts? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
    import wx

class spinnerFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent,id, "Spinner Frame", size = (300,200))

        #constants
        spnr_sz = (50,-1)
        names = ('name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6')


        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        # TEXT FONT EXAMPLE
        # m_text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Hello World!")
        # m_text.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        # m_text.SetSize(m_text.GetBestSize())

        #temp
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        row = 0
        for n in names:
            row += 1
            my_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, n)
            spinner = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, size = spnr_sz, min = 0, initial = 10 )
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnCompute, spinner)
            sizer.Add(my_label, (row,0))
            sizer.Add(spinner, (row,1))

        sizer.AddGrowableRow(7)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(4)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Centre()

    def OnCompute(self,event):
        # a = spinner.GetValue()
        # ????

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(True) # was False
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    frame = spinnerFrame (parent=None, id = -1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The easiest way I know is to associate your unique name with each call to Bind, either by giving the spinner a name or using partial functions (or lambdas, but lambdas can end up being messy), and then check for the name in the handler.  Examples of how to use the name are given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976395/best-way-to-get-the-name-of-a-button-that-called-an-event) previous SO question.

Comment: Great! This works for what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much!